# Combined Enum in Flow Type

Tags: javascript, enums, flowtype

I have an enum that is the combination of two other enums (all string literals) in `flowtype`.

Now I have a function `f1` that just accepts part of the enum. Based on an `if` clause, I want to make sure to pass only correct arguments to this `f1`.

If I use `if` to match on strings, it works. But as soon as I have a variable with the exact same string, it errors.

See code:

[Link to Flow-Playground](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCiAdgK4C2AjGALxgDkAhnWAD70BGdA3BjvseQBMNegGNuvPIVJkAzCIGVW0oT1Si4RAM7owokXXE9gwMFoZl82AE5x2MXGTABLKGACSYEltwAuVCZ6mjp6vipkwrSG3GCo6sG6UFS0ABS4FGGKFACUNAB8QdpwDgB08ADmaTlqgegAFs5aYAhw1gDWWvHaiZFgabKZMrK51AUA3qhgLm79YACE1FHiuRNTU0n92TxTAL6oewGm9Y1g7Na4DB1gALTNdZgA-F0hUPKpuAPhw-lgq9N9H3miz0K0maw2Hy2YL2B1qDSaLXanQ03TAUAALCJ+oNyN9Rr8wa4AfIFrRRKC1sSaMDomAHvRmGEIcNstD9nEgA)

Why does f3 error?

```html
/* @flow */
type Enum1 = 'a' | 'b';
type Enum2 = 'c';
type Enum3 = Enum1 | Enum2;

const c = 'c';
// same problem if I use:
// const c: Enum2 = 'c'; 

const f1 = (e1: Enum1) => console.log(e1);

// this works
const f2 = (e3: Enum3) => {
  if (e3 !== 'c') {
    f1(e3);
  }
}

// this breaks - why?
const f3 = (e3: Enum3) => {
  if (e3 !== c) {
    f1(e3);
  }
}

// this works
const f4 = (e3: Enum3) => {
  if (e3 !== c) {
    (e3 === 'c' ? '' : f1(e3))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type refinements need to be done with literals.  This might also be a conflict with refinement invalidations - the call to `f1` could invalidate the refinement, through modifying the value of var `c`.

```
const f3 = (e3: Enum3) => {
  if (e3 !== 'c') {  // literal c, not var c
    f1(e3);
  }
}
```

In effect, you're doing that same thing in `f4`, because you are comparing to literal `c` and only calling `f1` if its equivalent to `Enum1`

Comment: So your change is then `f2`, in my above list. But I see your point on the invalidation, I never thought about it that way. I did also try to type the `c` as `Enum2`, but still, same issue. But I have some understanding why that is.

Comment: Do you know, is that somewhere in the official doc?
Thanks for answer, will upvote and accept soon

Comment: https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/ - That doesn't talk about the comparison being done to a literal, but you need to remember that Flow does static type validation, not at runtime, so what you put in a variable is not universally tracked because it can't.  This is why refinement invalidations are documented, anything that can have a side effect at runtime could invalidate flows idea of what's valid.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that for refinements to work the identity operator `===` has to be used; Flow won't "accept" a refinement when using the equality/equivalence operator `==` (because of coercion, if I had to guess).